# Good javascript library for visualising a graph of organisational hierarchy data?

Tags: library, javascript, data-visualization, graphs

I am looking for a JS visualisation library that allows me to display a graph which shows company ownership, and attributes of those companies/relationships. So something that would [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKv79.png) (with pretty CSS) and allow me to have:

Nodes as organisations which can be different colours.

Edges as relationships between organisations which can be different arrow types.

Attributes on both nodes (ID, company asset value, industry, etc.) and edges (relationship type, ownership percentage, etc.) to be visible when a node/edge is selected.

Make the graph zoomable/attributes editable/move nodes around.

I've looked at libraries available like Google Chart, Vega, Dracula, TreantJS, etc. but none of them seem to allow me to do this from what I've seen. Have considered using D3 to do all of these since I know it's powerful enough, but I want to make sure there's no libraries that could save me some time.

Answer (score 1):

[Diagram](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-diagram) is a feature-rich JS component for visualizing, creating, and editing interactive diagrams like flow charts, organizational charts, mind maps, BPMN diagrams, and more. Its rich feature set includes built-in shapes, editing, serializing, exporting, printing, overview, data binding, and automatic layouts.

Herewith we have a created a sample to display a graph that shows company ownership, and attributes of those companies/relationships with our Diagram’s [Nodes](https://nam02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fej2.syncfusion.com%2Fjavascript%2Fdocumentation%2Fdiagram%2Fnodes%2F&data=04%7C01%7Cnaganathanganeshbabu%40syncfusion.com%7C7106ab0c3c784033593208d8d950ce89%7C77f1fe12b04949198c509fb41e5bb63b%7C0%7C0%7C637498288370411710%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=EFRy0bqSzZVfSIPHvjCP8iJeOD16%2BFaA6nNAJVsFOxs%3D&reserved=0) and [Connectors](https://nam02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fej2.syncfusion.com%2Fjavascript%2Fdocumentation%2Fdiagram%2Fconnectors%2F&data=04%7C01%7Cnaganathanganeshbabu%40syncfusion.com%7C7106ab0c3c784033593208d8d950ce89%7C77f1fe12b04949198c509fb41e5bb63b%7C0%7C0%7C637498288370421701%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=a9fburA3GdJbTt9Mv9SGZ%2FbpTMPlWGfMdB5FBxTraDk%3D&reserved=0).

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/n7vehc-81wyvr

For further information, please refer our [help documentation](https://nam02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fej2.syncfusion.com%2Fjavascript%2Fdocumentation%2Fdiagram%2Fes5-getting-started%2F&data=04%7C01%7Cnaganathanganeshbabu%40syncfusion.com%7C7106ab0c3c784033593208d8d950ce89%7C77f1fe12b04949198c509fb41e5bb63b%7C0%7C0%7C637498288370431701%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=IdVNz3trmX84x6iYqTu2whav56AkDYR2JPxYDTC1rn8%3D&reserved=0)

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license program](https://nam02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.syncfusion.com%2Fproducts%2Fcommunitylicense&data=04%7C01%7Cnaganathanganeshbabu%40syncfusion.com%7C7106ab0c3c784033593208d8d950ce89%7C77f1fe12b04949198c509fb41e5bb63b%7C0%7C0%7C637498288370441695%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=Jorpfl689g5Sc2GCT2aochnxEl6jBMEZjYyMxgH%2FrGQ%3D&reserved=0) if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.
Note: I work for Syncfusion

Answer (score 0):

you can use [BALKAN OrgChartJS](https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS)

BALKAN OrgChartJS lets developers to create simple, flexible and highly customizable organization chart for presenting structural data in an elegant way.